# What are steps to deploy Angular 17 SSR on nginx (Windows version)?

Tags: angular

I have built a sample project comes up with default Angular 17 SSR. The are two folders (Browser and Server) inside dist folder of the project. I don't know which one should be used in SSR mode.
Please guild me through steps needed to deploy Angular 17 SSR?

Comment: You know that you need node to run ssr right ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes, I can run it in development. My problem is in deployment. Why is there two folders inside dist folder?

Comment: Take the server folder. The other one is for CSR.